# Rxjs subject with multiple observers with debounce subscribe only the last one

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-subscriptions

I have an angular v7 application where i am using Rxjs subject. Following is the partial code. I am using the subscription with multiple methods. But only the last subscription is working and not the others.

```
this.userSelectionChangeSubscription = this.userSelectionChangeSubject
    .pipe(debounceTime(environment.saveDebounceTime))
    .subscribe((saveCallback) => {
        this.reloadColumns();
        saveCallback();
    }); 

//on change of a dropdown 
onPremiumBasisChanged(premiumBasis: number[]): void {
    this.onUserSelectionChanged(() => this.saveMethodParameters());
}   

onDevelopmentMethodsChanged(developmentMethods: number[]): void {
    this.initialData.selectedDevelopmentMethods = developmentMethods;
    this.onUserSelectionChanged(() => this.saveMethodParameters());
}       

onUserSelectionChanged(saveCallback: () => void): void {
    this.userSelectionChangeSubject.next(saveCallback);
}   

private saveMethodParameters() {

// actual save code goes here

}
```

What is the correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: I only see one subscription (3rd line). What do you mean by "only the last subscription is working"?

Comment: OnInit of the component, both PremiumBasis and DevelopmentMethod changed is triggered.At this stage, even though both OnPremium... and OnDevelop.. notifies, only the premium is getting subsribed and not the DevelopmentMethod one.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/). I can't tell from the provided code why one works but not the other.

Comment: this happens when both the change event happens at same time. so because of debounce time, only the last one executes.